# Allowing cell phone through home firewall

Tags: networking, firewall

I'm trying to make it so I can allow my cell phones dynamic IP address to be set as allowed on my incoming firewall at home.

Does anyone know a good method for this or is VPN and sshing my only options here?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you allow remote computers to access your home network without VPN?  Seems the same for your cell phone as I understand it.

Comment: No I don't allow remote users. I'm trying to allow my cell phone as a specific device/ip be assigned as an exception. The problem is cell phones IPS change all the time and I can't seem to find a solution like a dynamic dns for at home in how it would assign a host name for the ip and gets updated via automatic as it changes and then I could allow that host name as my exception.

Comment: If you are not allowing remote users, what exactly are you trying to do?  The phone would be a remote user.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I don't have it allowed unless by exception which is what I'm trying to make for my phones ip address. By default all external access is blocked and I want my phone as an exception.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is not to limit by IP. e.g: use a vpn, or use port knocking, or use some other identifier than an IP.

port knocking would be my suggestion, (and is what i do).

Comment: Not my cup of tea, but I've heard, but never validated, that some mobile providers might be using [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), where at any point in time multiple end-devices share the very same public IP address. If true, and when assuming that port knocking opens access on IP-address level, this would **in theory** also allow the other devices access. Also, I've heard but never validated that IP addresses might change quickly when moving from one cell tower to another, requiring a new port knocking sequence to be initiated?

Comment: yes, and it would indeed. Which is why i use it to allow access to my SSH port, which is still locked down by all the usual methods (publickey, nopassword etc). I wouldn't use it if CGNAT was in place, or if there was no other security in use. Dunno about the changing ips on cell towers, i guess i tend to be standing still whenever i've tried !

Comment: further, i guess if CGNAT is actually in use any kind of IP based control is going to be a bad idea.

Comment: I'm trying to do it so only my phone has access to my web servers which host my network control links. I know it can be done with ssh tunneling and vpns, but if I wanted to got locked out of my von or ssh which i know not likely but if i did i was wanted a way to just connect to those sites but only allow from a set of allowable ips or devices. Sadly porr knocking does not work with my equipment.